# Can’t find best way for apply best in code design techniques in software dev

Tags: mvvm, tdd, domain-driven-design, entity-framework-core

**[Pre]**

I have to say that I'm dummy newbie who is trying to get together important puzzles with such crucial details as DDD, TDD, MVVM, and EFCore. I have an about 10 years of windows form develop experience in complete wrong manner, and after I'm joined to Plurasight I'm understood that I'm just  lost my last 10 years, and this is really sad :).

**[Problem description]**

I have an App that i want to re-write from scratch by using latest and greatest technics that've learned for the last 6 month on Pluralsight, but the problem is that these new knowledge’s is stopping me, because simply I'm afraid that I'll do it wrong again...(that is stupid I know, but it is what it is).

So back to my questions, I have a big problem domain, and pretty well documented business logic, which i have to turn in to the code. I'm understand that my start  point is design data layer, for these purposes I  want to use Entity framework core (I saw Julie Lerman's course on Pluralsight and I think's she is amazing and inspires me to use EFCore as ORM for my app). But at the same time leakage of experience produces more questions than what I’ve learned with Pluralsight, and I will try to write them all(please don’t judge me too hard)

1. It is looks like that I will need 2 or even more data model projects in my solution, and here is why I have multiple document set types, each of the type contain more than one reference books used to generate unique file names and data sheets. But it looks weird to me have 3 Data model projects such as MyApp.PackType1.DataModel, MyApp.PackType2.DataModel, and each of them will be preinstalled with the EFCore, and each of them will generates its own database based on Data Context defined by EF. Isn’t it very redundant or this is correct way?
2. I don’t understand how to join these multiple Data Models projects, including Shared Kernel into the one nice model
3. I don’t understand what is the best way to design my data classes? Should they be just POCO’s or I can design them as nice looking classes with the private var’s and public properties? What are the best practices in here?
4. Also I don’t understand what is the best practice to use a MVVM pattern on top of that, and is it applicable at all to use MVVM in this case?
5. Should I keep my Tests in separate projects like MyApp.PackType1.DataModel.Tests, or keep them in same project?
   Best regards,
   Maks!

P.S.

Apologize for unclear definitions and questions, English isn't my native language.

Comment: How about some text formatting.

Comment: "I'm afraid that I'll do it wrong again"; don't be _afraid_ of mistakes, _plan_ for them.  Look for coding patterns and habits that make mistakes easy to delete.

Answer (score 0):

It's very complicated to answer your question because you have asked for a lot of details, but I going to provide a brief answer and I hope it will be helpful.

1. You can have only one model for your entities (DDD) and create sub model from this model in your end level projects (Web API or UI)
2. Read point #1
3. You have to create an Entity Layer project that represents your database and then you can create DTO's for specific scenarios
4. From my point of view, use Angular but you can use another UI framework such as React or VueJs, but I prefer to use Angular to build UI interfaces and consume .NET Core Web API from client
5. Create unit tests and integration tests for you Web API projects and as additional feature you can use Db in memory provider for tests

May be this guide is useful: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1160586/Entity-Framework-Core-for-Enterprise

Regards

Answer (score 0):

1. Hm, multiple DbContexts (models) usually come about when you have distinct databases you are using.  General rule is one Context = one Database.  Exceptions can occur when there are a lot of tables that can be grouped functionally, but there are downsides to that approach.
2. A DbContext is a repository pattern but for individual tables.  Using a Unit of Work pattern and layering with a custom repository provider would allow you to make it "appear" as a single database, hiding the complexity from the front-end.
3. Your entity descriptions are usually created as straight POCO.  You can get creative with different DTOs
4. In a nutshell, an MVVM pattern goes like this:

   - Request from UI to a controller
   - Controller possibly issues multiple calls to Data Layer to gather data
   - Assemble data in a single ViewModel (everything the page needs)
   - Return to UI
   - The beauty of the approach is single roundtrip (request/response) to the UI
5. Separate Project in my opinion.  There are techniques to spoof the database connection using EF so you are not using "live" data.

That CodeProject article will come in handy.